# N sys.argv[1:] args with optional args XOR 1 argparse arg, with 1 optional arg?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

In the event that the `--mac` `argparse` argument is set, I'd like to disallow any further command line input via `sys.argv`. Is this possible?

The script that I'm writing should be able to take `N` `sys.argv[1:]` arguments, or (XOR) a single `--mac` argument with a positional argument for the MAC address to be queried.

Currently, `N` `sys.argv[1:]` are being passed to construct a query string to be sent to a REST API.

**I'd like to be able to do this:**

```
if args.mac is not None: do_MAC_operation()
else do_BizBar()
```

**What I have so far:**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() parser.add_argument("-v" "--verbose", action="store_true", help="verbose output")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True) 
group.add_argument("-m", "--mac", action="store_const", const="mac_address" help="search by MAC address") 
args = parser.parse_args()
```

### Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a bit of post-processing, since you won't know until run-time how many positional arguments are allowed.

```
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-m", "--mac", action="store_const", const="mac_address")
p.add_argument("addresses", nargs="*")

args = p.parse_args()

if args.mac is not None and len(args.addresses) > 1:
    p.error("Only one argument allowed in conjunction with --mac")
```

Another option is to create two options for the mutually exclusive group instead of
using positional arguments. One will take a single argument, the other can take
an arbitrary number.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True) 
g.add_argument("-m", "--mac", dest="addresses")
g.add_argument("--nonmac", nargs="*", dest="addresses")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here, I'm letting the argument processor take care of the mac-vs-nonmac question. After you'e parsed the arguments, you won't be able to tell if an `args.addresses` of length 1 came from `--mac` or `--nonmac`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in the original question. The script would optionally perform an operation on a SINGLE MAC address in the event that the --mac flag was specified. In the event that the --mac flag is passed, I'd like to disallow the use of any other flags.